# Splitting lines in python

Tags: python, text, split

```
text = "                            ABCD-10630Re: Alert: abc.server.com/kafka stauts Status,ABCD-10629Re: Alert: db01.server.com/Replication lag,ABCD-10601Re: Alert: web-app.server.com/apache service down check,ABCD-10571Re: Alert: slave01.server.com/Replication lag,
"
```

I get the above text from a curl output and some cleaning up of HTML tags. I want to be able to split the tickets(see the below example) from the rest of the text and print them out separately using python.

Example:

```
ABCD-1063O           Re: Alert: abc.server.com/kafka stauts Status,
ABCD-10629           Re: Alert: db01.server.com/Replication lag,
.
.
.
```

please help.

Comment: Did you attempt anything at all, or did you just want someone to do your work for you?

Comment: do you really need to keep ',' ? If no, you can just split it like this text.split(',')

Answer (score 1):

```
 split_list = text.split(',')

 for i in range(len(split_list) - 1):
     re_index = split_list[i].index('Re')
     print "{0}      {1}".format(split_list[i][0:re_index].strip(), split_list[i]
     [re_index:].strip())
```

Comment: plus 1 , for use python built-ins , but note that using `index('Re')` is not an efficient way because its possible that there was another `Re` in text. in this case its better to use `regular expressions` based on look-around . also always add the result of your code to the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall`

```
>>> text = "                            ABCD-10630Re: Alert: abc.server.com/kafka stauts Status,ABCD-10629Re: Alert: db01.server.com/Replication lag,ABCD-10601Re: Alert: web-app.server.com/apache service down check,ABCD-10571Re: Alert: slave01.server.com/Replication lag,   "
>>> re.findall(r'([A-Z]+-\d+)(Re[^,]+,)', text)
[('ABCD-10630', 'Re: Alert: abc.server.com/kafka stauts Status,'), ('ABCD-10629', 'Re: Alert: db01.server.com/Replication lag,'), ('ABCD-10601', 'Re: Alert: web-app.server.com/apache service down check,'), ('ABCD-10571', 'Re: Alert: slave01.server.com/Replication lag,')]
>>> for (x,y) in re.findall(r'([A-Z]+-\d+)(Re[^,]+,)', string):
        print(x+"\t"+y)


ABCD-10630  Re: Alert: abc.server.com/kafka stauts Status,
ABCD-10629  Re: Alert: db01.server.com/Replication lag,
ABCD-10601  Re: Alert: web-app.server.com/apache service down check,
ABCD-10571  Re: Alert: slave01.server.com/Replication lag,
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very reliable but it might fit your purpose:

```
 mylist = text.split(',')
 for i in mylist:
     print (i);
```